# Is "the set of continuous and monotonically increasing functions on an interval" finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Original question:
If continuity is the only requirement, here is the solution: [Dimension of space of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500513/dimension-of-space-of-continuous-functions)
But the proofs use trigonometric functions and polynomial functions, which are not monotonic.

A further question is, what if I would like to impose additional features on the functions, say, concavity? It seems that one has to search for new bases if using constructive proof because the bases in the original proof may not satisfy the additional feature. I was wondering whether there is a generic way of proof to circumvent this problem (My guess is that no matter what the feature is [as long as the set is a linear space], the set of functions with this feature on an interval is infinite-dimensional).

Edit: Thanks for pointing out it is not a vector space. So I changed my question (I thought this new question is equivalent to the original question but it turned out they are not).

Edit again [revoked]: I think maybe I should add another constraint that the functions are bounded, or even more stringent: the codomain is an interval...Otherwise, the answer seems to be obviously "No".

Comment: Sum of two monotone functions doesn't have to be monotone. Also be more clear that you're talking about normed vector spaces

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you for pointing this out. I have changed "monotonic" to "monotonically increasing". As for the norm, I thought it is a topological feature, while dimension is an algebraic feature, so why does the norm matter?

Comment: The norm doesn't really matter, I agree. But I disagree that it's a topological feature, it's more rigid than that. I'd say it's a feature of... a normed vector space :P

Comment: @Jakobian I asked the wrong question anyway. Please see the updated one.

Comment: After edit this became a **completely** different question. And my current answer in no way addresses that. Instead of making such drastic question change, how about you revert it, accept the answer and ask another question? At the moment this is chaos.

Comment: @freakish I agree. I revoked the edit and asked a new one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749322/is-the-set-described-in-the-main-text-a-polytope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the set of continuous and monotonic functions on an interval

That is not a linear space. At least under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. A sum of increasing and decreasing function does not have to be monotonic.

> the set of continuous and monotonically increasing functions on an interval

That is not a linear space as well. Because if $f$ is strictly increasing then $-f$ is strictly decreasing, i.e. is not increasing. Even in weak sense, which is required anyway to keep the zero (i.e. $x\mapsto 0$ map) of the space.

> I was wondering whether there is a generic way of proof to circumvent this problem

No, there is no generic way.

> My guess is that no matter what the feature is [as long as the set is a linear space], the set of functions with this feature on an interval is infinite-dimensional

No, take all functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ of the form $x\mapsto ax$ for all real numbers $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Or even simpler: all constant functions. Both spaces are of dimension $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the first point, I am sorry I made the mistake. I have changed "monotonic" to "monotonically increasing".

Comment: @Ypbor that doesn't change much, that is not a linear space as well.

Comment: My bad. I did not realize the coefficient of linear combination can be negative...So now I realize I asked the wrong question. My real question (which I thought was equivalent to finite dimension) is whether this set is a polytope.