# Is the set described in the main text a polytope?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Definition: the convex hull of a finite subset of a vector space is called a polytope.
Consider the set of continuous, non-decreasing, and (weakly) concave functions whose domain and codomain are both $[0,1]$. Is this set a polytope?

I guess the answer is "No". So I tried to prove this by taking any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ functions in this set, and then construct a function that cannot be written as a convex combination of these functions. But I do not really know how to construct...

In addition, I feel that even if I replace "continuous, non-decreasing, and (weakly) concave" with other features, the answer should still be "No". I was wondering whether there is a generic method of proving this.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $f_n(x) = 1 - (1-x)^n$ for positive integers $n$ are continuous, non-decreasing, concave, and map $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.  Since they are linearly independent, they can't all be convex combinations of some finite set of functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on why 1. $\left\{f_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ae linear independent; 2. They being linear independent implies they can't all be convex combinations of some finite set of functions?

Comment: 1) They are linearly independent because they are polynomials of different degrees.  A linear combination of polynomials of different degrees has the same degree as the polynomial (with nonzero coefficient) whose degree is highest. 
2) A convex combination is a linear combination.  The span (i.e. space of linear combinations) of $n$ polynomials has dimension at most $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer is great, here's a similar example, with details. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define:
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx & \textrm{ if } x \in [0, n^{-1}]\\ 1 & \textrm{ else.}\end{cases}$$ Let $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary finite subset with at least two elements, and suppose, for sake of contradction, there exist not-all-zero scalars $\alpha_i$, $i \in N$ such that:
$$ 
\sum_{i \in N} \alpha_i f_i(x) = 0
$$
for all $x \in [0,1]$.  Since $f_i(1) = 1$ for all $i$, this means that:
$$\tag{$\ast$}
\sum_{i \in N} \alpha_i = 0.
$$
Let $n',n''\in N$ denote, respectively, the smallest and second smallest numbers in $N$ whose $\alpha$'s are non-zero. By ($\ast$),
$$
-\alpha_{n'} = \sum_{i \in N \setminus \{n'\}} \alpha_i,
$$
and both sides of this equality must be non-zero.
But at $x = n''^{-1}$, every $f_i(n''^{-1}) = 1$ except for $i = n'$. Thus:
$$
0 = \sum_{i \in N} \alpha_i f_i\big(n''^{-1}\big) = \alpha_{n'}f_{n'}\big(n''^{-1}\big) + \sum_{i \in N \setminus\{n'\}} \alpha_i = \alpha_{n'}f_{n'}\big(n''^{-1}\big)  -\alpha_{n'} \neq 0,
$$
a contradiction. Thus for any $N$, the family $\{f_i(\cdot)\}_{i \in N}$ is linearly independent, and since $N$ can be chosen to be any (finite) size, the set $\{f_n(\cdot)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ cannot be contained in any finite dimensional subspace of $C([0,1])$.